# How to import all default types in a TypeScript Definition file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

Current situation (simplified):

```
type OneCtrl = import("some-package").default.OneCtrl
type TwoCtrl = import("some-package").default.TwoCtrl

declare module "my-package" {
    export function useUtils(options: OneCtrl): TwoCtrl
}
```

**I am having to repeatedly import individual types from the default import.**

Using `<reference>` didn't work.

I tried `type g = import("some-package").default` and then using `g.OneCtrl` but that didn't work either.

I am importing from a package that has a namespace. Direct ES6 imports would result in the definition file not being an ambient definition anymore which is what I need otherwise the project gives errors.

Environment (For Context): Vite + Vue 3 + TS Project

---

**Update on specifics**

I am trying to add types to this external package [vue-grapesjs-composables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-grapesjs-composables) which is based on the original [grapesjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grapesjs) package which does have types.

What I mean by having tried ES6 imports is that this would work in the definition file:

```
import type grapes from 'grapesjs'

declare module "vue-grapesjs-composables" {
    export function useGrapes(editorConfig: grapes.EditorConfig): grapes.Editor;
}
```

but gives this error when I import it in a component:
`Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-grapesjs-composables'`

Comment: "Direct ES6 imports" and "Using <reference> didn't work" - what exactly did you try? It's not a common situation for the types to be `default` export. If it applies to a specific package, please, list it, so it could be tested

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask. I have added some specifics in the question to hopefully provide more clarity. Perhaps I will modify the title if the error mentioned is the main issue and could be solved.

Comment: Try to move import statement inside declare, also try to `import` and not `import type`, this can make a difference

Comment: Moving import inside declare worked... Thanks! Still using `import type` but `import` works as well.